# Cannot use module Puppeteer in electron

Tags: node.js, electron, puppeteer

### Problem

I cannot understand how to use `Puppeteer in Electron` NPM module. I copied the code from the npm page and tried to run it but gives the following error:

`Error: The parameter 'app' was not passed in. This may indicate that you are running in node rather than electron`

### Objective

My objective is to execute the script on the press of a button (in headless mode).

### Code

```
//api/test.js


const {BrowserWindow, app} = require("electron");
const pie = require("puppeteer-in-electron")
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
 
const main = async () => {
  await pie.initialize(app);
  const browser = await pie.connect(app, puppeteer);
 
  const window = new BrowserWindow();
  const url = "https://google.com/";
  await window.loadURL(url);
 
  const page = await pie.getPage(browser, window);
  console.log(page.url());
  window.destroy();
};

module.exports = main;
```

```
//HTML script

const main = require("../test");

document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', runScript)

function runScript(){
   main()
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?